# trying to get the user details from mysql database got an error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the user details form mysql database by using the below query

```
                    $rows=array();
         $query = "SELECT CONCAT(usrFirstname,'',usrSurname) As FullName,usrNickname AS            Nickname,";
      $query.= "usrEmail As EmailAddress,usrGender AS Gender,DATE_FORMAT(usrDOB,'%d%m%y') As DOB,usrBelt AS BeltId";
      $query.= "FROM user";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
     echo mysql_error();
if($result)
{
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
       $rows[] = $row;
  }
}
```

it was giving error like this

ERROR:
             You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no space between `usrBelt AS BeltId` and `FROM`.

Answer (score 1):

Try do add a space before from clause

```
$query.= " FROM user";
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space in front of the word `FROM`.

```
  $query.= "usrEmail As EmailAddress,usrGender AS Gender,DATE_FORMAT(usrDOB,'%d%m%y') As DOB,usrBelt AS BeltId";
  $query.= " FROM user";
```